# PIL doesn't detect identical images

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to determine if an image layer (mainLayer) will be visible within a final image, in which it will be underneath layer, layer2 and layer3. I need to do this without knowing what those other layers are. All of these image layers are RGBA; they also have the same dimensions (2048x2048) and file format (.png).

Here's the code I have so far:

```py
# Create compImage1, which is all of the layers that go on top of mainLayer
compImage1 = layer.copy()
compImage1.paste(layer2, (0, 0), layer2)
compImage1.paste(layer3, (0, 0), layer3)

# Create compImage2, which is mainLayer with all of the other layers added
compImage2 = mainLayer.copy() # I want to determine this layer's visibility in the final image
compImage1Copy = compImage1.copy()
compImage2.paste(compImage1Copy, (0, 0), compImage1Copy)

# Compare compImage1 and compImage2; if layer, layer2, and/or layer 3 completely obscure
# mainLayer, then there should be no difference between the two images    
difference = ImageChops.difference(
    compImage1.convert("RGB"), compImage2.convert("RGB")
).getbbox()

if not difference:
    print("mainLayer will not be visible")
else:
    print("mainLayer will be visible")
```

This code prints "mainLayer will be visible" when mainLayer is not covered by layer, layer2, and/or layer3. However, it still prints "mainLayer will be visible" when mainLayer is covered by one of those layers.

Why is this code not working correctly? Is there a better/faster way to do this?
Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT:
I was asked to clarify what exactly I'm asking:

I have 4 image layers: mainLayer, layer, layer2, and layer3. I am putting them together into one image. I do not know the positions or sizes of any of the visible portions of these layers; they are all 2048x2048 image layers, and most of each image layer is transparent.

I need to know if mainLayer will be completely covered by any combination of layer, layer2, and layer3 (case 2), or if it will not (case 1). My code works for case 1, but not case 2. [Here is a diagram depicting cases 1 & 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K11Cy.png)

Comment: `Image.getbbox` will always return a 4-tuple unless the image is completely empty and has no dimensions, in which case it would return `None`. A 4-tuple is always truthy, so the condition `not difference` will never be true. What were you expecting `difference` to look like?

Comment: You aren't showing any images. And your code is incomplete and cannot be run. And your question is not very easy to understand. Can you click [edit] please and try to improve it so folks can help you better? You seem to be interested in whether something will be visible somehow through 2 layers of something else, so far unspecified, maybe? Thank you.

Comment: @PaulM. I had expected it to return `None` if `ImageChops.difference()` returned an `Image` where every pixel value was equal to 0. Looking at the documentation now, I realize that I misunderstood what exactly `Image.getbbox` does. I just tried converting the `Image` returned by `ImageChops.difference()` to a numpy array then iterating through it to find any nonzero values. However, this didn't work either.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not allowed to share any of the actual images I'm using; I also cannot show the rest of the code. However, I edited my post and tried to make my question clearer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first observation is that the solution purely depends on the alpha channels of the images - the RGB channels are irrelevant.

My second observation is that the solution only depends on the bounding box of the alpha channels on the base image - anything outside that is irrelevant.

So with that in mind, I'll start like this and discard the RGB channels and crop to the bounding box of the base image to save time and RAM:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load base image, extract alpha channel and bounding box and crop to it
base = Image.open('base.png').getchannel('A')
bbox = base.getbbox()
print(f'Base image bbox: {bbox}')
base = base.crop(bbox)
base.save('DEBUG-base.png')

# Load overlying layers, extracting alpha channel, cropping and making into Numpy arrays
layers = []
for layer in [0,1,2]:
   filename = f'layer{layer}.png'
   print(f'Loading {filename}')
   im = Image.open(filename).getchannel('A').crop(bbox)
   im.save(f'DEBUG-{filename}')
   layers.append(np.array(im))
```

---

Note that you can comment out any line containing the word `DEBUG` if you want to do timing or understand simpler code.

You can also clean up after running very simply by doing:

```
rm DEBUG*.png
```

Note that because I formed the DEBUG images by multiplying a Boolean True/False image by 255, the True areas will show up white and the false areas will show up black.

The next thing is to make boolean masks of the various conditions so we can easily think about just one aspect of the problem at a time and combine the masks simply at the end. Mask operations are *very* fast in Numpy.

```
# Make PIL Image of base layer into Numpy array
base = np.array(base)

# So we now have base and all layers, just alpha channels, cropped to bounding box as Numpy arrays
# We want to find areas where:
# a) base is non-transparent - we call this "maskA" and store as Numpy array
# b) any layer fully opaque - we call this "maskB" and store as Numpy array
maskA = base > 0
Image.fromarray((maskA*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('DEBUG-maskA.png')
maskB = (layers[0] == 255) | (layers[1] == 255) | (layers[2] == 255)
Image.fromarray((maskB*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('DEBUG-maskB.png')

# result is where there IS something in base layer and there is NO overlay that is fully opaque
res = maskA & ~maskB
Image.fromarray((res*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')

# Reduce result to simple Yes/No by seeing if any pixel is True
print(f'Result: {np.any(res)}')
```

---

So, if I use these images as `base`, and `layer0-2`:

[image]

It runs like this:

```
Base image bbox: (80, 800, 301, 951)
Loading layer0.png
Loading layer1.png
Loading layer2.png
Result: True
```

And if I use these images, the answer is `False`.

[image]

---

Note that I made the images with **ImageMagick** like this:

### Case 1

```
#!/bin/bash
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill red  -draw "rectangle 80,800 300,950"    PNG32:base.png
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill blue -draw "rectangle 280,700 480,850"   PNG32:layer0.png  
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill lime -draw "rectangle 320,1000 460,1200" PNG32:layer1.png
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill orange -draw "rectangle 500,800 800,900" PNG32:layer2.png
magick base.png layer0.png -composite layer1.png -composite layer2.png -composite PNG32:case1.png
```

---

### Case 2

```
#!/bin/bash
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill red  -draw "rectangle 80,800 300,950"    PNG32:base.png
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill blue -draw "rectangle 70,700 350,900"    PNG32:layer0.png  
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill lime -draw "rectangle 50,900 250,1200" PNG32:layer1.png
magick -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill orange -draw "rectangle 250,900 800,1200" PNG32:layer2.png
magick base.png layer0.png -composite layer1.png -composite layer2.png -composite PNG32:case2.png
```

---

Note that if your base and/or layers contain partial transparency, and/or *"holes"*, and/or discontiguous areas of transparency, and/or ragged edges, you will need to check carefully the DEBUG images my code produces to be sure I have covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dorky, but you could create a function that, given an image, returns all pixel-coordinates (as xy-tuples) that are opaque (non-transparent) as a set. Then iterate over all combinations (powerset?) of layers, merge the current layer combination into a single image, and take the difference between the set of opaque pixel-coords in the main layer and the set of opaque pixel-coords in the current combined layer image. If any of the layer combinations entirely obscure the main layer, we end the loop prematurely. Pseudocode:

```
def get_opaque_coords(image):
    # Return all pixel coords that are not completely transparent
    return set((pixel.x, pixel.y) for pixel in image.get_pixels() if pixel.color.alpha != 0)


main_layer = Image.open(...)

layers = [
    Image.open(...),
    Image.open(...),
    Image.open(...)
]

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    from itertools import chain, combinations
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

for selected_layers in powerset(layers):
    merged_image = merge_into_single_image(*selected_layers)
    if not(get_opaque_coords(main_layer) - get_opaque_coords(merged_image)):
        print("The following selected layers entirely obscure the main layer!")
        print(selected_layers)
        break
else:
    print("None of the layer combinations entirely obscure the main layer.")
```